# Bad Picking Error in Python

Tags: python, pickle

I am currently working on a system to transmit data between Named Pipes. When I try to setup a listener to read it, I'm getting a weird error. This error only occurs when I'm passing multiple messages into the pipe.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/learn_pipes.py", line 96, in extract_from_pipe
    message = pickle.load(pipe_rd)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: bad pickle data
```

This is my receiving method:

```
def extract_from_pipe(self):
    with open(path, "rb") as pipe_rd:
        while True:
            try:
                if(os.path.getsize(path) > 0):
                    print(path)
                    message = pickle.load(pipe_rd)
                    print(message)
                    with self.arrived_condition:
                        self.communication_queue.put(message)
                        self.arrived_condition.notify()
            except EOFError:
                time.sleep(0.01)
```

and this is how I'm picking the data:

```
def send(self, pid, *values): #Works
    with open(path, "wb") as pipe:
       pickle.dump(values, pipe)

for num in range(1000):
    me.send(consumer, 'message', num + 1)
```

Any ideas what the problem could be? I'm unsure why this is bad pickle data when it works when I only pass one instance of send?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the initial pickle-file and trying it again?
Also using the highest protocol could help `pickle.dump(values, pipe, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`

Comment: I am using the same pipe to transmit more information though, would that be wise to delete the initial pickle file?

Comment: You mean, the "pipe" is actually a pipe and not a file on your filesystem and you use that pipe not only to dump data from pickle?
In that case it is no wonder, you're getting data-corruption.
Look into the pickle-file and determine, if there is other data in there, that hasn't been pickled.

Comment: Your receiver will not make sure that you have exactly one message to unpickle. It could load a partitial one when writing from the other side is not finished, yet, or more than one if they are written quickly. Both wont work.